# Call to a member function revoke() on null exception

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am trying to create a logout function in laravel Passport.

```
public function logout(Request $request) {
        $user = Auth::user()->token();
        $user->revoke();
        $tokens =  $user->tokens->pluck('id');
        Token::whereIn('id', $tokens)
            ->update(['revoked'=> true]);
        
        RefreshToken::whereIn('access_token_id', $tokens)->update(['revoked' => true]);
    }
```

I got this exception on postman. Is there someone who can help me for this? How can I solve this

> Call to a member function revoke() on null

problem

```
"message": "Call to a member function revoke() on null",
"exception": "Error",
"file": "/Users/123/Desktop/Projeler/Passaport Api/App/app/Http/Controllers/ApiAuth.php",
"line": 52,
```

Comment: It is because no user is logged in and you are trying to log "him" out

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the route inner the passport Auth middleware like below:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function() {    
 Route::post('logout',   [YourNameController::class, 'logout']);
});
```

hopefully that is help you

Comment: 'CSRF token mismatch' I got a alert like that

Comment: Add the following line to the head tag. `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"> // Add in <head></head>
`   
Add the following line to the head tag.

<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"> // Add in <head></head>
Then get you can get this content attribute in Laravel. Also, in your script tag, add the following code (this is to make sure when you submit the form, you get the correct  `csrf_token`    `$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});`

Comment: I get this problem on postman. how can I solve it?